# Do I need to recompile my PECL extension for each new version of PHP?

Tags: php, pecl

I'm starting out building a PECL extension and notice I have to include PHP source in the build process - does this mean I will need to build my extension with each individual version of PHP I wish to support or will a PECL extension built with an old version of PHP run with a new one?

Comment: As long as it not depends on bleeding edge features, you can build your extension to work with all PHP5 versions.

Comment: Right ok, thanks...so it would be very unlikely PHP authors would change something fundamental within PHP5 say that would stop all old extensions working?

Comment: Nothing is guranteed, also they did. But you can add a version switch.. Like this: https://github.com/metashock/php-pcap/blob/master/pcap.c#L178

Comment: Right ok, thanks for that link - nifty.